# Android System Programming

Tags: system

As android is based on a Linux core, is it possible to use POSIX System Programming tools, techniques and libraries to program and customize the environemnt like I would have done on my Ubuntu for example ?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This site is for *users* of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry, I am new to this section.

Comment: You're welcome. General hint: All SE sites have a `/help/on-topic` page. So if you're new to a site and want to post your first question, it's always a good idea to check that first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Android is "Mostly POSIX-compliant" and that it is available through the Android NDK. Which can be found [here.](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

According to Wikipedia for what its worth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX